# Function that derives the components of a vector with respect to it's direction

Tags: python, function, math

I'm trying to derive a simple function\'s that specify the magnitudes of the components c and e on the y axis respectively (seperately). Given a vector that transitions from left to right, I would like to calculate the magnitude of c(component of Y) with respect to the magnitude of the delta between DF and DE and and the magnitude of d with respect to the magnitude of the the delta between CA and AB, whereby the magnitude is a 1:1 correlation. I need it to be functional for all six transitions so the value on the Y axis would be indicative of the type of result. I.e. categorically e would be different from c. and e would be inversely proportional to c.
Provided the vector crosses the Y-axis I need to still be able to quantify the magnitude of c and e as shown in figure 1.

[image]

Seen as though I only need to quantify c (uses the start of the vector whereby c is proportional to a) and e (end of the vector calculated by start (CA/DF) + delta whereby e is proportional to d) I need not specify the entire vector (simple line). end is simply start + delta
I have tried to implement this in python as follows (numbered parameters linked to numbered graphs (4-6 ommitted from graphs)):

```
# delta = change from initial value to next value

# 1) start = -9, delta=18
# 2) start=-9, delta=8
# 3) start = 1, delta=8
# 4) start = -1, delta=-8 --ommitted
# 5) start = 9, delta=-8 --ommitted
# 6) start = 9, delta=-18 --ommitted

def calc_comp(start=-9, delta=8): # 2) implementation
   c = max((start+delta),0)
   e = min((start+delta),0) 
   return c, e
```

However this obviously does not account for all cases shown above, I'm not sure how best to implement this whilst accounting for all possible transitions(6) some advice on how I would best be able to accomplish this would be great, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, late night ... is that better?

Comment: `#3` - starts at 1 on the x axis, and the delta is positive 8. How dose line `f` end up in quadrant IV? Does the the orange line always have a `+x/-y` slope?

Comment: "e would be inversely proportional to c" -- do you mean that they are of opposite signs? I don't see how they would be inversely proportional (which would mean e.g. if c is 9 then e would be something like 1/9).

Comment: If an orange line crosses the x axis does it have to pass through (0,0)? If `start= -8` and `delta= 18` is `c=8` and `e=10`?

Comment: It would help if you would give the expected output for each of those 6 cases

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I think that the following should work:

```
def signed_parts(a,b):
    #assumes a < b
    if b <= 0:
        return b-a, 0
    elif a >= 0:
        return 0, a-b
    else:
        return -a, -b

def calc_comp(start, delta):
    if delta >= 0:
        return signed_parts(start,start + delta)
    else:
        return signed_parts(start + delta, start)
```

Comment: hmmm, I like this but I envisioned a `+x/-y` slope for a positive delta and `-x/+y` for a negative delta. Question isn't very clear.

Comment: @wwii I agree that the question isn't very clear. The function I wrote seems to match the cases for which there is a drawing, but even there the intended output is more guessed than clearly stated. In any event, OP can perhaps tweak this code if it doesn't cover all cases.